# Install Debian Package in chroot

Tags: chroot, debootstrap, systemd-nspawn

I am building a minimal Debian image with debootstrap, chroot in it and installing grub.

Now I need to install some custom self created debian packages. These packages have postinst scripts running database migrations. BUT in my chroot env the postgresql of course is not running.

I tried `systemd-nspawn` but without the `-b` flag the container is not booted and again the postgresql is not running.

Of course `apt install ...` fails and running `apt install` during the first real boot would probably rerun the postinst successfully but it feels ugly.

Is there a better way how to prepare a minimal clean bootable already configured image?

Answer (score 0):

Why not start PostgreSQL within your chroot before installing your custom packages?

By default systemd services won't run within a chroot, but you can still manually start PostgreSQL, e.g. something like this:

```
 su postgres -c 'pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l serverlog'
```

(Command taken from [PostgreSQL 11 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/server-start.html))

If it fails to start, check the serverlog file as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Running the image with `systemd-nspawn --boot`, waiting for it to boot and then running commands with `systemd-run` is working

```
#!/bin/bash

MACHINE_NAME=target$$

wait_for_container() {

  while true; do

    if machinectl | grep --quiet "$MACHINE_NAME"; then
      break
    fi

    echo "Wait for container $MACHINE_NAME"
    sleep 1

  done

  echo "Container up!"

}

poweroff_container() {

  machinectl poweroff $MACHINE_NAME

}

systemd-nspawn --boot --machine $MACHINE_NAME --directory "$MOUNT_PATH" > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# wait until container is up
wait_for_container

systemd-run --machine $MACHINE_NAME --pipe --wait /bin/bash <<EOF 

  # do your stuff
  hostnamectl set-hostname your-hostname

EOF

poweroff_container
```